# Combinatorics proof counting

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinatorics-on-words

The question is counting the number $b_{p,q}$ of binary strings with no consecutive $1$’s, with a $0$ at each end. With **q 1’s and p 0’s.**

> How do I prove $b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$ is equivalent to saying $b_{p,q}= b_{p-1,q-1}+ b_{p-1,q}$  **if $n = p+q$.** where **$n$ is the number of digits available**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This seems like a tough one.  Just to verify, do you intend that
in general, 
$$b_n = \sum_{p=0}^n b_{p,n-p}~~?$$
Am I correctly interpreting your intended relationship between
$b_n$ and $b_{p,n-p}~$?  Stating the question a different way,
does $b_{p,q}$ represent all binary strings with $p ~0$'s and $q ~1$'s,
or only such binary strings with no consecutive $1$'s?

Comment: @user2661923 only the strings with no consecutive 1′s. I added a pic for more clarification. towards the end I need to prove what I have in the question.

Comment: What about the *summation* equation in my previous comment.  Do you intend that that equation is accurate?  The reason that I mention this, is that otherwise, it is unclear whether $b_7$ specifically is referring to $b_{7,0}$ or $b_{6,1}$ or $\cdots$ or $b_{0,7}$, or whether $b_7$ is referring to the sum of these $b_{p,q}$ variables, where $p+q = 7.$

Comment: @user2661923 yes. the summation equation is right and should hold. You are interpretation is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is why $b_{p,q}=b_{p-1,q}+b_{p-1,q-1}$ implies $b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$:
$$\begin{aligned}
b_n 
&= \sum_{p} b_{p,n-p}
\\
&= \sum_{p} b_{p-1,n-p}+b_{p-1,n-p-1}
\\
&= \sum_{p} b_{p-1,(n-1)-(p-1)}+\sum_pb_{p-1,(n-2)-(p-1)}
\\
&= \sum_{p} b_{p,(n-1)-p}+\sum_pb_{p,(n-2)-p}
\\
&= b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: @user2661923 explained to me that  $b_{n}$ is the summation of $b_{p,n-p}$ that helps me understand what I was missing. Thank you very much mike your answer is very clear. I'll vote it up once I have enough reputation.